# How to debug this logical error in output of selection sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input("Enter no of elements "))
A = []

for i in range(n):
    A.append(input())

for i in range(len(A)):
    min_idx = i
    for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):
        if A[min_idx] > A[j]:
            min_idx = j
A[i], A[min_idx] = A[min_idx], A[i]

print("Sorted array")
for i in range(len(A)):
    print(A[i])
```

**Sample input:**

```
Enter no of elements 4
11
55
22
3
```

**Output:**

```
Sorted array
11
22
3
55
```

The output has one element remaining in unsorted position. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

You have an indenting error:

**Sorting Code:**

```
A = [11, 55, 22, 3]
for i in range(len(A)):
    min_idx = i
    for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):
        if A[min_idx] > A[j]:
            min_idx = j
    A[i], A[min_idx] = A[min_idx], A[i]  # <== this line was not indented enough
```

**Output Code:**

```
print("Sorted array")
for i in range(len(A)):
    print(A[i])
```

**Produces:**

```
Sorted array
3
11
22
55
```

**But, Python is Wonderful:**

Python has some great tools for this sort of thing, highly recommend you use them.  This will give the same output as all of the above code:

```
A = [11, 55, 22, 3]
print("Sorted array")
for number in sorted(A):
    print(number)
```

This demonstrates two things.

1. Iterate on the list itself, you don't need indices here.
2. Let Python sort it for you.